# Parent class is undefined in javascript module

Tags: javascript

I have `ToastWithButton` class the extends `Toast` class, however I get error `Toast is undefined` when trying to extend it.
inside my toast.js

```
module.exports = class Toast{
    constructor(message,type){
        this.message = message
        this.mesage = type //success, error
    }
}

module.exports =  class ToastWithButton extends Toast{
    constructor(message, type, button){
        super(message,type)
        this.button = button
    }
}
```

Comment: declare the `Toast` class and then do `module.exports = Toast` (Same applies for the other classes)

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: Just do `class Toast{...class code...} module.exports = Toast;`

Comment: check srimaln91's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use export like this.

```
class Toast{
    constructor(message,type){
        this.message = message
        this.mesage = type //success, error
    }
}

class ToastWithButton extends Toast{
    constructor(message, type, button){
        super(message,type)
        this.button = button
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Toast,
    ToastWithButton
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that module exports should be placed in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import toast class(module) before extending it.